# what is the correct syntax for node-webkit chromium args?

Tags: json, node-webkit

In my package.json file for node-webkit I have: `"chromium-args" : "--url="http://www.google.com""` I tried to use use backslashes \"www.google.com\", but webkit seems to not open at all when uses blackslashes.  If I leave the blackslashes out, webkit loads the window but produces a JSON syntax error.

package.json file code:

```
{
  "main": "index.html",
  "name": "nw-demo",
  "description": "demo app of node-webkit",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "keywords": [ "demo", "node-webkit" ],
  "window": {
    "icon": "link.png",
    "toolbar": true,
    "width": 800,
    "height": 500,
    "position": "mouse",
    "min_width": 400,
    "min_height": 200,
    "max_width": 800,
    "max_height": 600
  },
  "webkit": {
    "plugin": true
  },
  "chromium-args" : "--url=\"http://www.google.com\""
}
```

What is the correct json syntax to for "chromium-args"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for 'url' you might write in in the 'main' field.

For quoting it could be written this way '--key

Comment: I replaced my main field with the url of a remote website and that worked as expected.  I did try that before posting my question, but node-webkit was not working as expected.  I think the initial trial and error I was not compressing the files correctly.  This time I deleted my app.nw and started from scratch.  Now webkit seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of double quotes use single quotes

`"chromium-args" : "--url='http://www.google.com'"`